# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play.services-vision

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to built my first ever android app. So in that process I follow some old Video tutorials and in that process messed up my tool versions. While I am trying to sync my gradle with various versions of

> com.google.android.gms:play.services-vision:

But each time it is failing. And I also couldn't get hold of latest version of this one. I am using the following version of Google Play service:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play.services-vision:11.6.0'
```

But it is failing. Am I missing anything ?
My dependencies are :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Add lib

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play.services-vision:11.6.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue try adding maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to list of repositories in project level build.gradle (root gradle) as shown below.

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
 }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have google() in my repositories. Do I need to enter     " maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } "

Comment: which version of studio are you using ?

Comment: I am using verson 3.1.3

Comment: not required in that case. it should work for you. try invalidating and restarting studio once.

Comment: I tried using    " implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1 " and it seems OK till now.